# Tag For Overcoming Magical Obstacles

Tags: discussion, tags

@SerbanTanasa has been asking a series of questions recently about an [adventurer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/keeping-secrets-in-a-thought-reverberating-hall) named [Alice](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10939/how-to-defeat-a-precognitive-warrior) overcoming various [magical foes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11252/how-to-catch-a-dream-thief). The answers to these questions often involve creative solutions to magical or fantastical situations that would never occur in real life, but by using real-world skills. However, there is no single tag for questions like this.

I think there should be a tag for questions involving a real-world solution to a magical problem/foe/obstacle. I'm not really sure what to call it, but I want it to exist. Thoughts?

Comment: It could probably be as simple as "magical-battles" or "magical-obstacles".

Comment: It might be a good tag if more people demonstrated interest in it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's needed, but if so, I propose [tag:antimagic], [tag:anti-magic] or [tag:magic-counter].  They'd be specifically for dealing with non-magical ways to counter magic, on any scale (not just individuals)

Comment: @Bobson I would really like to have an [tag:antimagic] tag. I would find questions to ask about it, just so I could use the tag.

Comment: My vote would be for anti-magic

Comment: I'm not really sure that anti-magic is the correct word. overcoming-magic is more descriptive in it's name, I think

Comment: A good exercise for "I think we might need a tag for this" cases is to try to write the tag wiki.  Without just saying "like Serban's questions", how would you characterize the questions that should get this tag?

Comment: Related: [Distinguishing science and fantasy based questions](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/39/29) and particularly [Grace Note's answer to that question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/51/29).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to borrow Monica Cellio's comment from the question, here:

> A good exercise for "I think we might need a tag for this" cases is to try to write the tag wiki. Without just saying "like Serban's questions", how would you characterize the questions that should get this tag?

That's really it. **Start out** by actually *defining* what the tag should be all about. Write that down. Try to condense it into maybe 2-3 sentences for the tag wiki excerpt as well.

If you can meaningfully describe the tag within that space, such that someone coming across the tag will know when it should be used, then it might be worth adding it to the relevant questions, putting the tag wiki on it (attract the attention of high-rep users in chat if you don't have the rep to make tag wiki edits of your own) and see if it takes off. We can always cull it later if it turns out that it didn't actually fill a need.

Comment: I agree with both your answer and your comment, and I feel like I've dealt with both. I want to know when these questions exist because they're useful to me and I love trying to answer them, and I think my question here has done some preliminary wiki-writing.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

**Conflict Resolution**
For questions about possible results of specific conflict situations.

or

**Challenge Solution**
For questions about solutions to specific challenging situations.

?

It seems to me that this would cover more questions, and could be combined with [magic] or whatever to cover solutions to magical problems

This would also be good for Dustin Jackson's questions about defeating specific wizards, or questions such as HDE 226868's about imprisoning wizards who can walk through walls. The first one would also cover questions like Dustin's [Sapient Ant Colony Rivaling Homo Sapiens and Homo Neanderthal?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/sapient-ant-colony-rivaling-homo-sapiens-and-homo-neanderthal)

Note we do have a **Conflict** tag, but it has no description, and is only applied to one question (the ant/neanderthal one linked directly above).